# Azure Bot Download source code button not working

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I created a new Web App bot from azure portal, and trying to download a source code of bot from BOT Management=> Buid=> "Download Bot source code".

But the button is not working and it is not doing any action. Has anyone faced the same issue or anyother workaround?

Comment: Which navigator and its version? OS and its version? Currently when I click on it I got "Preparing your download uri... Creating source zip file", I have to wait something like 30 seconds and this display changes to "Your download uri is ready. Download source code of your bot", with buttons to download. So it's working on my side.

Comment: Window 10, tried with firefox and ie both. when i clcik the button no action is happening.

Comment: Which Web App Bot template did you use?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's console window (F12)?

Comment: @EricDahlvang No error in console window, but it acts like disabled button, but not disabled (I'm using QnA bot template)

Comment: Is the QnA template for Node or C#?

Comment: its a QnA bot for c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a C# QnA template bot in Azure and did not have issues downloading the source code.

Nonetheless, another alternative is to use the **Kudu** console for the Web Application:

Navigate to https://[YourAzureWebApp].scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

and download the wwwroot folder:

[image]